# What verb should I use here?

Tags: word-choice

Premise: I want to become a bad man for a little while. What verb would fit here?

Let me ___ a hateful man

I think "become" or "be" may be too strong considering it's just going to last some minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you will find a single word to fit your sentence, but the following work well enough I would say:-

> Let me **experience being** a hateful man
>
> Let me **try being** a hateful man
>
> Let me **experiment as** a hateful man

Comment: One question. If I say "let me be a hateful man", what is it that I'm conveying?

Comment: @TheBeast This depends on the context. To answer in light of your original question first, you could 'be a hateful man' for a second , hours, days, years or a lifetime. So the phrase does not exclude the use you have mentioned (where you are going to be hateful for a short period of time) however it also doesn't make it explicit, that you are *only* going to be hateful for a short period of time either, which the above phrases do a better job of intimating. In terms of what is being conveyed. You are conveying the desire that you 'want to' exist as a hateful man. / continued

Comment: Depending on the tone, this could mean just that literally, or it could mean, something is preventing you from being a hateful man, and you want whatever is preventing you to be gone, such that you can 'be a hateful man'.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **embody**?

```
Let me embody a hateful man.
```